# How to use docker (kitematic) like xampp works?

Tags: php, mysql, docker, kitematic

I'm trying to learn how to use docker (I have to use kitematic because I'm not able to use commands, so everything I do I do it in kitematic, so please don't tell me about commands). I'm using docker toolkit for windows 10.

What I'm trying to achieve:
I want something like xampp. I mean: creating/managing databases with phpmyadmin and a folder where I can store my projects folder (something like htdocs in xampp) so I can run and test my php scripts. Even if I have to use (for example) wordpress, I want to be able to browse the wordpress root, navigate files, edit them, etc. But wordpress is only one of the things I need to test, I also need to run plain php pages. I also want 2 php containers I can run on my choice (example: if I want to test something with php 7.4 I run a container, if I want to test with php 5.6 I run another).

I tried to create apache containers (httpd), php containers, mysql containers, etc. But maybe there's something I don't get.
If I start the mysql container I have the mysql engine but I can't manage databases. So I start the phpmyadmin container but it runs on its own, not linked to mysql (if I start the phpmyadmin container but not the mysql and php ones, it works too... why?) and I can't access it because I don't know what credentials I should use.
If I start the apache container I don't see any way to browse files so I can store project files.
Only the mysql container tells me how to configure it (setting the root password). Other containers just don't. The php container starts and close immediately.

Comment: Hi @thebestofbests, can you try to narrow the issue? The problem you are presenting it quite wide. I would start with one of the issues you are having and provide a sample of code/configurations you are using and the specific errors you are getting.

Comment: Hi @barbasa, the first thing I would do is having a web server working for php processing. Like, having a folder where I can put php files (for example index.php with only phpinfo in it) and call it to see the output. The database stuff can be done at last...

Comment: What have you been trying until now? Can you share the Docker images you have used, the errors you are getting, etc...and why you got blocked?

Comment: These are my containers: [link](https://freeimage.host/i/JOjKfR)

Comment: Maybe you wanted to look at docker files (something like *.yml) but note that I have to use kitematic and I don't know where to pick those files.

Comment: Configurations of each container are default (except for mysql, in which I only have set password root).

Comment: The (first) problem is I don't know how to store a php file in a project folder so I can call it in browser (via ip and port, probably). I don't know which containers I have to start and if I have to link each other.